# How to replace one dll in deployed azure worker role to modified version?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I need to replace one dll-file in deployed azure worker role to one that I modified, because role contains a bug and I don't have a release tag. I'm trying to do that via rdp, but when I'm trying to copy new dll into approot folder VM tells me that old dll file is open in another program and can't be replayced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a good idea.  You should do this by repackaging the deployment and performing an update.  By attempting to do this via RDP you may replace the file, but if the role goes down or gets moved then when Windows Azure bring the role back up the change will be gone since it will redeploy the last package it knew about, so you'd be back to the dll with the bug in it.

As for why it is telling you it is open is because the worker role is actively using it most likely.  You'd have to stop the worker role process to be able to replace it.  The best option is still to perform an update of the whole package.

You can see this documentation for more information about how the updates occur: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh472157.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply! What do you exactly mean by "role goes down"? I'm asking because when I kill process, replace dll and process starts again couple times - my new dll stays at place and everything fine. You mean situation when role need to reimag or reboot?

Comment: Correct, the instance can go down for many reasons: hardware issues, updates to the OS (both guest and host OS), patches, etc. There are many things that can cause your instance to reimage and when that happens it will revert to the previous deployment and your new DLL will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with MikeWo's suggestion about repackaging and updating the deployment. 
However, if you want to drop the single DLL and check to see if fix works. you can kill WaWorkerHost.exe - the blue highlighted process in the picture. then you can replace the DLL.

[image]